Resetting input fields after barcode-scan submit
I am currently working on an app for android using ionic/angular 10.0.0. In this app there is a feature where the user can map an article to a display using a barcodescanner. For my tests i am using a Zebra TC 58 running with android 11. The way it is supposed to work is, that after the first scan on the first input field it should set the focus to the second one, and after the second scan:

the form should be submitted
the mapping performed
both input fields cleared
the focus should return to the first field.

This is working so far, but in testing i noticed, that roughly 4 out of 10 times:

The second input field will not be cleared.
The focus does not change back to the first input field.

@Component({
  selector: "app-mapping",
  templateUrl: "./mapping.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./mapping.page.css"],
})
export class MappingPage implements OnInit, ViewWillEnter {
  @ViewChild("input1") displayInput;
  @ViewChild("input2") itemInput;

  public scannedCodeForDisplay: string;
  public scannedCodeForItem: string;

  private resetInputFields(): void {
    this.itemInput.value = "";
    this.displayInput.value = "";
    this.scannedCodeForItem = "";
    this.scannedCodeForDisplay = "";
  }

  public mapDisplay(): void {
    this.resetInputFields();
    (this.displayInput as IonInput).setFocus();
  }
}

<ion-grid>
    <form (ngSubmit)="mapDisplay()" #inputForm="ngForm">
            <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
                <ion-col size="12" class="ion-text-center">
                    <ion-label class="display-label">Display</ion-label>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center display-item">
                <ion-col size="9">
                    <ion-input
                        #input1
                        autofocus="true"
                        class="display-input"
                        placeholder="{{'general.display.mapping.dropdown.qr' | translate }}"
                        type="text"
                        [class.ng-invalid]="displayMissing"
                        [(ngModel)]="scannedCodeForDisplay"
                        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                        [class.ng-valid]="!displayMissing"
                        (keyup.enter)="setFocus(input2)"
                    >
                    </ion-input>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    <i class="fa fa-qrcode" style="font-size: 48px" aria-hidden="true" (click)="scan(true)"></i>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
    
            <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center grid__row--big-top-padding">
                <ion-col size="12" class="ion-text-center">
                    <ion-label class="display-label">{{'general.display.mapping.item' | translate }}</ion-label>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center display-item">
                <ion-col size="9">
                    <ion-input
                        #input2
                        (keyup.enter)="mapDisplay()"
                        class="display-input"
                        placeholder="{{'general.display.mapping.dropdown.qr' | translate }}"
                        type="text"
                        [(ngModel)]="scannedCodeForItem"
                        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                        [class.ng-invalid]="itemMissing"
                        [class.ng-valid]="!itemMissing"
                    ></ion-input>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    <i class="fa fa-qrcode" style="font-size: 48px" aria-hidden="true" (click)="scan(false)"></i>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
                  </form>
    </ion-grid>

I already tried using a timeout, which resolved the issue, but i don't want to use a timeout since i have heard that it is not good practice? Furthermore would i love to understand whats the issue, since after a lot of trying around I also noticed that this issue only arrives when using the scanner on the TC 58 and never when using the keyboard.
I also thought that it might be related to the response of the server being to slow, but even without doing anything (only resetting the input fields on submit, nothing else) it does not work.
I also thought that it might be related to changeDetection and tried manually telling angular to check for changes but that did not work either.
PS: I am no expert in angular, rather a beginner
PS2: This is my first question posted on here, so i am sorry if something is wrong/missing - feel free to correct me :)

Hey there ! I'm not used to Template driven form, is it possible for you to see if you encounter the same issue with reactive forms (https://angular.dev/guide/forms/reactive-forms) ? FMPOV it's more clear to work with reactive form ! more safe, more typed, ect...
